# How to check the positive and negative number's in a given arraylist in android or java?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have set of int Arraylist for my application.For example

```
int[] array={10,8,-4,-6,5}
```

Here i want to check this array list.i am using this array for my bar graph chart.if all the value contains positive value,i want to show the graph in 0 to 100 % Y axis.if array contains negative value,i want to show the negative axis like -50 to 100 % depends upon the value.

How to do the logic for this problem.can anyone help me for my application?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: use if else , this is very simple, first loop array then use if else

Comment: First try something yourself

Comment: `for(int i =0; i< array.length(); i++){ if(array[i] == 0) {LOG("LOG", "Element " + array[i] + " equals to zero");} else{ if(array[i] > 0){LOG("LOG", "Element " + array[i] + " is above zero");} else{LOG("LOG", "Element " + array[i] + " is below zero");} }` I can't belive I ate the whole thing ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean isNegative=false;
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
 {
    if(array[i]<0)
    {
      isNegative=true;
      break;
    } 
 }
    if(isNegative)
  {
   // code for displaying negative axis
  }
 else
   {
   //only display positive axis
   }
```